# How can I get the domain\user for the logged on user to the current session

Tags: c++, windows, wtsapi32

I am looking for a way to get the username and domain of the user that is logged on to the session that my process runs in. I can't rely on my process token info since it was created from the token of a different user and contains incorrect info.

I prefer a way that does not rely on WTS service.

I tried using [GetUserObjectInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28%22WINUSER/GETUSEROBJECTINFORMATION%22%29;k%28GETUSEROBJECTINFORMATION%29;k%28SOLUTIONITEMSPROJECT%29;k%28DevLang-%22C%2b%2b%22%29;k%28TargetOS-WINDOWS%29&rd=true) and then [LookupAccountSid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379166%28VS.85%29.aspx), but LookupAccountSid returns ERROR_NONE_MAPPED since "It occurs for SIDs that have no corresponding account name, such as a logon SID that identifies a logon session."

```
bool GetCurrentUserAndDomain(OUT wstring & user, OUT wstring & domain)
{
bool ret = false;

HWINSTA hWinStation = GetProcessWindowStation();
if (hWinStation == NULL) {
    //LOG_ERROR(L"Failed to GetProcessWindowStation");
    return false;
}

SID * pSID = NULL;
USEROBJECTFLAGS uof = {4};
DWORD requiredSize;

GetUserObjectInformation(hWinStation, UOI_USER_SID, NULL, NULL, &requiredSize);

pSID = (SID*) new BYTE[requiredSize];

if (!GetUserObjectInformation(hWinStation, UOI_USER_SID, pSID, requiredSize, NULL))
{
    //LOG_ERROR(L"Failed to GetUserObjectInformation2");
    goto end;
}

SID_NAME_USE sidType;
DWORD dwUserNameSize = 64, dwDomainNameSize = 64;
wchar_t szUserName[64], szDomainName[64];
szDomainName[0] = '\0';
szUserName[0] = '\0';

if (LookupAccountSid(NULL, pSID, szUserName, &dwUserNameSize, szDomainName, &dwDomainNameSize, &sidType))
{
    ret = true;
    user = szUserName;
    domain = szDomainName;
}

if  (GetLastError() == ERROR_NONE_MAPPED)
{
    // the SID is a Logon sid
}
end:
delete [] pSID;
return ret;
}
```

thanks

Comment: I don't know if there is any other way aside from WTS.

Comment: Yeah. I resorted to WTS, but I don't like it because sometimes I need it before the WTS service is up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GetUserNameEx API.
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724435(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724435%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: no go. the method raises a last error of: ERROR_NONE_MAPPED. odd.

Comment: Are you passing right value for 1st parameter? NameSamCompatible should be first parameter if you are looking for domain\user format.